# How to Install Tata Photon Plus (VME 101 Olive)?

Tags: mobile-broadband

I want to install VME 101 Olive with latest version of ubuntu also i need to know if there is any interface to run .exe files in the same.

Please help me i am a novice for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

You cant because .exe is the extension of winows executable files ,and you cant install windows drivers directly

here is the instruction to setup Tata Photon Plus (VME 101 Olive)  in linux

1. Plug in your device and you will notice the dialer on desktop , right click on the dialer and eject
   it.
   (Ejecting is compulsory )
   17
2. On task Manger right click on the icon highlighted and select the option “Edit Connections “.
   [image]
3. New window “Network Connections” will open > select Mobile Broadband option as displayed,
   [image]
   then click on “Add” option:
4. Select Forward without changing anything from drop down box:
   [image]
5. Select Forward again without changing anything from drop down box:
   [image]
6. Select TATA Indicom (Photon+) option & click on Forward:
   [image]
7. Select “Apply”
   [image]
8. After clicking “Apply” new window will pop up as displayed in picture below:

Fill the following details:-
Username –internet (small letters)

Password- internet (small letters)

[image]
Check the option “Connect automatically” & “Available to all users”, then click “Apply”.
20
8. After entering the details in above step, a pop up window will open and ask for password to
authenticate – you need to enter your admin password & after entering press authenticate.

[image]

9 . After authenticating the following window will be seen. Close the window.
[image]

10
Now single click on network connection and you will notice there will be a connection named as
“ Tata Indicom (Photon+) connection1 “ ----
Single click on the connection name & you will be connected to internet .

Comment: works perfectly on ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 0):

Without going into any technical details, right click on the network manager icon on the top right of your screen, go to edit connections and then select mobile broadband. My Huawei tata photon usb modem was detected . Chance are your will be detected too and then all you have to do is click next.

Answer (score 0):

your modem should be automatically detected in newer versions (11.10 onwards my experience)
you just have to wait for some time for the modem to be initialised then perform above proceedings.

1. Make sure to enter username=internet and password=internet
2. "Connect Automatically" is not necessary according to me because it requires a lot of time for modem initialization any attempt to connect to internet before that would compel you to remove and re-insert modem.
   Be patient

Answer (score -1):

I got answer here check out this guy wrote some thing new http://www.techspyder.net/how-to-install-tata-photon-plus-dashboard-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: ...And that link is now dead. There is [an archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20140911053040/http://www.techspyder.net/how-to-install-tata-photon-plus-dashboard-in-ubuntu/), though it might be somewhat hard to use without the images (which are not archived, and are referred to within the next to help explain what to do).